# Likely simple: MongoDB connects to database, but doesn't add items to it

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am following a tutorial online to make a simple CRUD node/express/mongo application. I can get this code to connect to the data base fine, but when I try to submit a quote to be added to the database, the console simply logs the data I've entered, and the data never actually gets added to the database. If anyone  could help me to understand why this isn't working, I'd appreciate it.

A possible issue may be, in MongoDB atlas my project is called testeru, my database is called test, and my collection is called quotes. I'm not sure if I improperly referenced this data?

I am running this on local host and I did whitelist my IP address in Atlas.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

//mongodb
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://OBSCURED:OBSCURED@cluster0.izcbs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(client => {
    console.log('Connected to Database')
    const db = client.db('test')
    const quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes')
  //  app.use{}
  //  app.get{}
    app.post('/quotes', (req,res) => {
      quotesCollection.insertOne(req.body)
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    })
  //  app.listen{}

  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))


//Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on 3000');
})

//Get request:
app.get('/', (req,res) => {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

})

//CREATE
app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

Comment: Did you set the right `content-type` header in your request ? Also, set the `app.use` body parser before your `app.post(...)` middleware is handled like a waterfall. Middleware define first, gets executed first.

Comment: Hi, Marc. I changed my code per your suggestion and also found a few errors along my way and now the issue is solved. A quick question for you can you send me a webpage or other resource that would help me to understand what you mean by content-type header in my request? Thanks so much

Comment: If you send some payload within a http reuqest, you should describe what kind of content it is: "content-type": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type